# IntelliJ auto-completion preferences

Tags: autocomplete, intellij-idea, preferences

... is there a way to change the color of the library name shown next to suggestion when using javascript auto completion? For instance right now I'll have something like : 'css jQuery(jquery-1.6.js)' and jQuery(jquery-1.6.js) is displayed in light gray on light green-ish background. Is there a way to change that to a different font/color for the lib name?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible right now. [Submitting request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA) would help to get it implemented in the future.